# Forward Action from Menu to parent class

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I am diving into a JAVA application and I am trying to clean things up from an overloaded main file to a more compartmentalized design.

I moved the menu to its own Class per this [tutorial](http://forum.codecall.net/topic/50111-jmenubar/).

In the `init()` method of the main class I have something like:

```
JMenuBar myMenu = new MainMenu();
setJMenuBar(myMenu);
```

In the class `MainMenu` I have created a menu. The menu shows up and I can capture the menu clicks within `MainMenu` but I need to trigger some activity in the class where `myMenu` was actually created.

I am using something like this:

```
someMethod(){
  ....
  noteReadingMenuItem.setAction(doSomething);
  ....
}
```

I have created the `Action` as a private member of `MainMenu` at the top of my class like this:

```
private Action doSomething = new AbstractAction("Do Something", new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/icon.png"))   ) {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {    
        //Do local processing here
    }
};
```

In reading through the docs, there seemed to be other ways of creating the actions, or just use `.addActionLister(this)` so its handled in `actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)` of the `MainMenu` class (which implements `ActionListener`).

How can I notify the Main class, or for that matter other classes about the menu action?

I have tried to "dispatch" the message based on some other posts, but I don't know how to receive it in the Main class, it is not received in the `actionPerformed()` of the Main class and no errors are handled:

```
java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemEventQueue().postEvent(e);

Component source = (Component) SwingUtilities.windowForComponent(parent);

source.dispatchEvent(e);
```

.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First Method**

Simplest way would be to maintain a reference to your Main class in MainMenu and call it's some notify method.

Check the following code.

```
JMenuBar myMenu = new MainMenu();
myMenu.setMain(this);//this is the Main class reference
setJMenuBar(myMenu);
//setMain inside MainMenu
public void setMain(Main main) {
    this.main = main;
}
```

Where Main class has notifyMain method

```
public class Main {
    ...

    public void notifyMain(Object notification) {
        //do something with notification
    }
}
```

Now since MainMenu has a reference to Main class it can call notifyMain method on it.

**Second Method**

Another way would be to access Main instance from an anonymous class.

For that we have to make JMenuBar an abstract class adding an abstractMethod notifyMain()

```
abstract class MainMenu {
    public abstract void notifyMain();
}
//inside Main class
JMenuBar menu = new MainMenu() {
    public abstract void notifyMain(Object notification) {
        Main.this.notifyMain(notification);
    }
};
```

Now once again MainMenu has a reference to Main class but it doesn't have to declare a dedicated field to it. It's maintained in kind of functional closure form.

Advantage of this method is that you can do the same thing in other classes and notify them in the same way as below.

```
//Inside Other Class
JMenuBar menu = new MainMenu() {
    public abstract void notifyMain() {
        Other.this.notifyMain();
    }
};
```

**Third Method**

Third method is a design pattern, Observer Pattern. Since @Saibot already wrote about it in his answer, there's nothing more for me to add here.

Comment: The first method seems to work but instead of `JMenuBar myMenu = new MainMenu()` you had to make it a type of `MainMenu` in the declaration `JMenuBar myMenu = new MainMenu();`

Comment: For me, the key thing I was missing was how to send the reference for the parent back to the child for the instance of the parent -`myMenu.setMain(this)` is probably the key I needed. I ended up just modifying the constructor of `MainMenu` to take and set the `this` of the Main class

Comment: I can now see that something similar was done in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16637894/separating-components-into-classes .

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Observer Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern).

Steps:

1. *Implement* *Observer interface* in classes which you want to be *notified*
2. *Extend Observable class* in classes which will *notify Observers*
3. Add *Observer* to *Observables* using:

   ```
   addObserver();
   ```
4. When something changes which you want to be notified, call:

   ```
   setChanged();
   notifyObservers();
   ```
5. Implement *update()* method on *Observers*, as this method will be called, when a notification happens.

Also read Java Docs here for Observer: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Observer.html

And here for Observable: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Observable.html

You don't need to implement anything, it's all in JDK.

[image]

Comment: ActionListener has a different role, you would probably use an ActionListener too in this pattern. I recently wrote a tetris game with this pattern, using ActionListener and KeyListener.

Comment: Swing's listeners are a form of a observer pattern, but they simply provide more focused information then the `Observable` API does, but that's just my opinion ;)

Comment: I agree. Observable&Observer is more flexible, they are generalized versions of listeners, or listeners are specialized versions. I got your point.

Comment: This feels familiar to what I've used in other languages. MainMenu already extends JMenu so multiple inheritance is not possible. I did find this example: http://www.javaquizplayer.com/blogposts/blogpost7.html#examplecode it looks like observable is put into a utility class and then send the messages. I think in this case @11thdimension 's answer is less reusable in the general sense, but easier in this case since it requires the least amount of handling back in main.

Comment: Actually, anything that can send a message about the event to the Main class can work, I agree. And there may be shorter solutions, I agree with it too. But I find the Observer pattern elegant and easy to understand solution to this. I just like, and shared it.

Answer (score 1):

## You could...

Add `ActionListener` support to your `MainMenu` class, maybe something like...

```
public class MainMenu extends JMenuBar {

    //...

    public void addActionListener(ActionListener listener) {
        listenerList.add(ActionListener.class, listener);
    }

    public void removeActionListener(ActionListener listener) {
        listenerList.remove(ActionListener.class, listener);
    }

    protected void fireActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        ActionListener[] listeners = listenerList.getListeners(ActionListener.class);
        for (ActionListener listener : listeners) {
            listener.actionPerformed(evt);
        }
    }

}
```

You could then register an `ActionListener` with the `MainMenu` class, when you create, from your main class.

Then, in your `Action` class, you would simply call the `MainMenu`'s `fireActionPerformed` method

But, frankly, this tends to defeat the point of using a `Action`, instead...

## You could...

Define a contract between the `MainMenu` and your main class, which describes the expected operations that your "main" class can perform, for example...

```
public interface ApplicationAction {

    public void save(File file);
    public void open(File file);

    public void exit();

}
```

Then your main class would implement this interface and your `MainMenu` would allow you to provide a reference to it (and possible others, like `EditAction`s?)

```
public class MainMenu extends JMenuBar {

    //...

    private ApplicationAction applicationAction;

    //...

    public void setApplicationAction(ApplicationAction applicationAction) {
        this.applicationAction = applicationAction;
    }

    public ApplicationAction getApplicationAction() {
        return applicationAction;
    }

}
```

Then in your `Action`s, you could simply execute the required functionality, for example...

```
public class OpenAction extends AbstractAction {

    private ApplicationAction applicationAction;

    public OpenAction(ApplicationAction applicationAction) {
        this.applicationAction = applicationAction;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // Use a JFileChooser to allow the user to select the file
        if (action == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            File selectedFile = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
            applicationAction.open(selectedFile);
        }
    }

}
```

## You could...

Simply create the `Action` classes without the need for a `MainMenu` class and use a factory or builder pattern to construct an instance of `JMenuBar` with the `Action`s you need

Comment: Can you expand on your first example, my MainMenu class is started with: `public class MainMenu extends JMenuBar implements ActionListener {` will `fireActionPerformed` make it so the event will be picked up in the Main class by the `actionPerformed` method in "main"? In the second example, I do not see how the Main class is getting connected. For this project, I am trying to fix up some spaghetti code. Since it's hard to follow I cannot move the actual execution code around yet, I need to just call what's in place (e.g., the original code has `inits` which call `starts` and flags upon flags.

Comment: The second example has a `setApplicationAction` which allows you to specify the instance of `ApplicationAction` to be notified when something happens, you would need to supply a implementation to it (much like you specify a implementation of `ActionListener`)